# Change InAnimation and outAnimation in ViewFlipper in AppWidgetProvider SubClass

Tags: android

I have a widget with an appwidgetPrvider class, in this class I have a RemoteViews that has a viewFlipper, when I want to update RemoteViews, I need to change inAnimation and outAnimation dynamically; 
How can I do this? I don't have accessibility to viewFlipper

I Wrote these codes but it didn't have any affect

```
View view = remoteViews.apply(context,null);
        ViewFlipper flipper =(ViewFlipper)view.findViewById(R.id.myViewFlipper_smal);
        flipper.setInAnimation(animateIn());
        flipper.setOutAnimation(animateOutTo());
        remoteViews.reapply(context.getApplicationContext(), view);
```